# How to upload multiple music files simultaneously to a single column in mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am a beginner in php but I am creating a project of music download website using php and mysql.
I want to upload multiple songs in a single column but below the code is not working.

I have three tables: album, artist, and music.

```
album table

+================================
| album_id | album_name | poster|
+================================
|          |            |       |
|          |            |       |
+===============================+

arist table

+==========================
| artist_id | artist_name |
+==========================
|           |             |       
|           |             |       
+=========================+

music tabel

+=====================================+
| artist_name | album_name | song_name|
+=====================================+
|             |            |          |
|             |            |          |
+=====================================+
```

I want to insert all the data at once in all the above tables. 
My code is as below:

```
<?php

   $album_name1=$_REQUEST['txtmovie1'];
   $album_name2=$_REQUEST['txtmovie2'];
   $album_name3=$_REQUEST['txtmovie3'];
   $album_name4=$_REQUEST['txtmovie4'];
   $album_name5=$_REQUEST['txtmovie5'];

   $artist1=$_REQUEST['txtartist1'];
   $artist2=$_REQUEST['txtartist2'];
   $artist3=$_REQUEST['txtartist3'];
   $artist4=$_REQUEST['txtartist4'];
   $artist5=$_REQUEST['txtartist5'];


  if(isset($_REQUEST['cmdSubmit']))
        {
        $con =  mysql_connect("localhost","root") or die("");
        $db=mysql_select_db("omg",$con);

//Movie Poster Upload 

//poster1
        $target_file="upload/".$_FILES['upsongs1']['name'];
        $source_file=$_FILES['upsongs1']['tmp_name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($source_file, $target_file))
        {
        $poster1=$_FILES['upsongs1']['name'];
        }
        echo $poster1;
//poster2
    $target_file="upload/".$_FILES['upsongs2']['name'];
        $source_file=$_FILES['upsongs2']['tmp_name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($source_file, $target_file))
        {
        $poster2=$_FILES['upsongs2']['name'];
        }
        echo $poster2;
//poster3
    $target_file="upload/".$_FILES['upsongs3']['name'];
        $source_file=$_FILES['upsongs3']['tmp_name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($source_file, $target_file))
        {
        $poster3=$_FILES['upsongs3']['name'];
        }
    echo $poster3;
//poster4
    $target_file="upload/".$_FILES['upsongs4']['name'];
        $source_file=$_FILES['upsongs4']['tmp_name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($source_file, $target_file))
        {
        $poster4=$_FILES['upsongs4']['name'];
        }
    echo $poster4;
//poster5
    $target_file="upload/".$_FILES['upsongs5']['name'];
        $source_file=$_FILES['upsongs5']['tmp_name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($source_file, $target_file))
        {
        $poster5=$_FILES['upsongs5']['name'];
        }
    echo $poster5;

//Song Upload

 //song1 Upload        
        $targets1_file="song/".$_FILES['txts1']['name'];
        $sources1_file=$_FILES['txts1']['tmp_name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($sources1_file, $targets1_file))
        {        $s1=$_FILES['txts1']['name'];
        }

 //song2 Upload        
       $targets2_file="song/".$_FILES['txts2']['name'];
        $sources2_file=$_FILES['txts2']['tmp_name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($sources2_file, $targets2_file))
        {        $s2=$_FILES['txts2']['name'];
        }

 //song3 Upload        
        $targets3_file="song/".$_FILES['txts3']['name'];
        $sources3_file=$_FILES['txts3']['tmp_name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($sources3_file, $targets3_file))
        {        $s3=$_FILES['txts3']['name'];
        }

  //song4 Upload       
        $targets4_file="song/".$_FILES['txts4']['name'];
        $sources4_file=$_FILES['txts4']['tmp_name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($sources4_file, $targets4_file))
        {        $s4=$_FILES['txts4']['name'];
        }


 //song5 Upload        
        $targets5_file="song/".$_FILES['txts5']['name'];
        $sources5_file=$_FILES['txts5']['tmp_name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($sources5_file, $targets5_file))
        {        $s5=$_FILES['txts5']['name'];
        } 


 $qry1=("INSERT INTO music(artist_name, album_name, song_name  ) VALUES('$artist1','$album_name1', '$s1'), 
VALUES('$artist1','$album_name2', '$s2'),('$artist1','$album_name3', '$s3'), ('$artist1','$album_name4', '$s4'),('$artist1','$album_name5', '$s5')");

 $qry2=("INSERT INTO album(album_name, poster) 

VALUES('$album_name1','$poster1'),
('$album_name2','$poster2'),
('$album_name3','$poster3'),
('$album_name4','$poster4'),
('$album_name5','$poster5')");

?>




<form  name="form1" method="POST" action="admin_new2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"            id="main" onSubmit="return check();">

<table>
<thead><tr> 
<th>Song</th>
<th>Movie/Album</th>
<th>Artist</th>
<th>Poster</th>
</tr></thead><tbody>                   

<tr >

<td>
<input type="file" name="txts1">
<input type="file" name="txts2">
<input type="file" name="txts3">
<input type="file" name="txts4">
<input type="file" name="txts5">
 </td>                          

<td>
<input type="text" name="txtmovie1">
<input type="text" name="txtmovie2">
<input type="text" name="txtmovie3">
<input type="text" name="txtmovie4">
<input type="text" name="txtmovie5">
</td>

<td id="artist-clm">

<input type="text" name="txtartist1">                            
<input type="text" name="txtartist2">       
<input type="text" name="txtartist3">           
<input type="text" name="txtartist4">               
<input type="text" name="txtartist5">
</td>

<td  id="poster">

<input type="file" name="upsongs1">                  
<input type="file" name="upsongs2">        
<input type="file" name="upsongs3">  
<input type="file" name="upsongs4">                 
<input type="file" name="upsongs5">

</td></tr>

</tbody></table>

<center><input type="submit" name="cmdSubmit" value="submit"></center>
 </form>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. A good question needs to state what's going wrong as precisely as you can along with a clear question. Code should be succinct.  In this case you may wish to simplify and handle one or two items at a time before trying to handle five.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this is because you must not repeat VALUES keyword when you insert many records with one query.

```
INSERT INTO music(artist_name, album_name, song_name  ) VALUES('$artist1','$album_name1', '$s1'), 
('$artist1','$album_name2', '$s2'), 
('$artist1','$album_name3', '$s3'),
('$artist1','$album_name4', '$s4'),
('$artist1','$album_name5', '$s5')
```

Then, for your next step, I know you are beginner but your code is not optimized. Instead repeat everything 4 times, see for a loop or store your data into an array :)

This will decrease your code size and maintaining it will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop and array for inserting the multiple records at a time.

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_REQUEST['cmdSubmit']))
    {
    $con =  mysql_connect("localhost","root") or die("");
    $db=mysql_select_db("omg",$con);
    //Movie Poster Upload 
    $s1=$poster1=$artist1=$album_name1 = '';
    for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
    {
    $artist1=$_REQUEST['txtartist'.$i];
    $album_name1=$_REQUEST['txtmovie'.$i];
    $target_file="upload/".$_FILES['upsongs'.$i]['name'];
    $source_file=$_FILES['upsongs'.$i]['tmp_name'];
    if(move_uploaded_file($source_file, $target_file))
    {
        $poster1=$_FILES['upsongs'.$i]['name'];
    }
    echo $poster1;

    $targets1_file="song/".$_FILES['txts'.$i]['name'];
    $sources1_file=$_FILES['txts'.$i]['tmp_name'];

    if(move_uploaded_file($sources1_file, $targets1_file))
    {        $s1=$_FILES['txts'.$i]['name'];
    }
    $query .= "('$artist1','$album_name1', '$s1'),";        
    $query1 .= "('$album_name1','$poster1'),";
    }



    $qry1=("INSERT INTO music(artist_name, album_name, song_name  ) VALUES '".$query."'");

    $qry2=("INSERT INTO album(album_name, poster)VALUES('".$query1."'");

    }
?>
```

Like this you can insert the multiple records.

Comment: Thanks for your code now its working and files are uploaded to folder, but database is not storing any data.

Answer (score -1):

song file are not be uploade ?  not work.???

```
        $targets1_file="song/".$_FILES['txts1']['name'];
        $sources1_file=$_FILES['txts1']['tmp_name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($sources1_file, $targets1_file))
        {        $s1=$_FILES['txts1']['name'];
        }
```